# Extract multiple blocks from a List

Tags: java, string, list, extract

I have a List of String which looks like this;

```
List list  =["BeginA","1","2","EndA","BeginB","3","EndB","BeginA","4","5";"6","EndA";"BeginC","EndC","BeginA","7","EndA"]
```

I need to extract from the list above  a sublist which contains blocs formed by all block of "BeginA" and "EndA", so the result will be somthing like this :

```
list sublist =["BeginA","1","2","EndA","BeginA","4","5";"6","EndA","BeginA","7","EndA"]
```

My initial list can contains multiple (n) blocks of "BeginA" and "EndA" and they are all consecutives, no nested blocks , after each begin block there is it's end block.

I used java.util.list properties "indexOf" and "lastIndexOf" but in this way, i was able to extract only two blocks .

Is there a way to extract all of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).equals("BeginA")) {
        while (!list.get(i).equals("EndA"))
            sublist.add(list.get(i++));
        sublist.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Loop over the array

  - if the current item is `BeginA`, set a flag
  - if the flag is set, copy the current item into a result array
  - if the current item is `EndA`, unset the flag